# What does Command + ("Bigger") actually alter in OS X Terminal?

Tags: terminal, applescript, command-line, shortcut, font

At first glance issuing <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> (View -> Bigger) in OS X Terminal simply increases the font size, and increases the window size while keeping the number of rows/columns the same. However, I can't seem to figure out what properties in Terminal are actually altered. For instance, I can list the properties of a Terminal window by applescript:

`tell application "Terminal" to tell window 1 to get properties`

If I issue this before and after issuing <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>+</kbd>, I can diff the outputs to get the resulting differences:

```
< selected tab:tab 1 of window id 63859
---
> selected tab:tab 1 of window id 63862
3c3
<  size:570, 365
---
>  size:570, 389
5c5
<  frame:310, 1492, 880, 1857
---
>  frame:310, 1468, 880, 1857
10c10
<  origin:310, 1492
---
>  origin:310, 1468
14c14
<  id:63859
---
>  id:63862
17c17
<  bounds:310, -1057, 880, -692
---
>  bounds:310, -1057, 880, -668
```

So the various properties controlling window size and location change, but notably the font size property *doesn't* change. I can change the font size manually using, e.g.:

```
tell application "Terminal" to tell window 1 to set font size to 20
```

and in a "clean" Terminal window this will in fact increase the font size.  However if I have already issued <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> this command will no longer alter the font size.

Lastly, in a "clean" Terminal window if I change the profile manually it will revert to the font size specified in the chosen profile. If I instead issue <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> beforehand this reversion will not happen.

What is it about <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> that overrides the font size property in Terminal? Is there some property of the app/window/tab that is changing that I don't have access to?

(Catalina/10.15.7 if it matters)

Comment: Have you considered using the Accessibility Inspector to see more of what's happening in that window? https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Accessibility/Conceptual/AccessibilityMacOSX/OSXAXTestingApps.html

Comment: @jasonology thanks I didn't know this existed!  It's a nice tool, but I'm still not seeing what's changing when I make the manipulations I described.  The mystery continues.

Comment: I just used the Console and watched the Activities in the Terminal app as I pressed cmd+. It tells me it is using AppKit /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit to run some internal code "performKeyEquivalent".
I also see an activity VBWAIT: announce remote view to VBA which is from /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ViewBridge.framework/Versions/A/
So it's just running portions of its compiled code. I hope this helps.